# How to make Invisible button in 'PricingCard' in react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I tried to use **[PricingCard](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/1.0.0/pricing.html)** from 'react-native-elements' with some of the changes like removing the button. As button element is required, so I tried to use **buttonStyle** object to make the button transparent. However, as you see the picture, it still exists. Is there any workaround for this?

```
      <PricingCard
              color="black"
              title="2020-05-20 11:00~13:00"
              titleStyle={{ fontSize: 24, color: "#f7b731"}}
              price="$120"
              info={["1", "2"]}
              button={{
                buttonStyle: styles.pricingButtonStyle,
              }}
            />
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pricingButtonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#00ff0000',
    width: 0
  },
});
```

https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/1.0.0/pricing.html#button

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the opacity of the button to be 0.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pricingButtonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#00ff0000',
    width: 0,
    opacity: 0
  },
});
```